# UIWebView's inside UIScrollView consuming touch events

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiscrollview

I have multiple custom UIWebView's as subviews within a UIScrollView. I have implemented the touch methods within the UIViewController for the UIWebView's, but these methods are not being called.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { }
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { }
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { }
```

I have read elsewhere and it says that the UIScrollView will consume the events. This makes sense, but should the UIWebView's not receive the touch event before the UIScrollView itself? What is probably happening, is that the UIWebBrowserView (a subview of the UIWebView) is consuming the events. This class can't be subclassed however, and so I can't send the events up the superview chain to the UIScrollView. I have read on the Apple iOS Documentation that one shouldn't ever place a UIWebView inside a UIScrollView, but I need to do so for my purposes.

So my question is: how can my custom UIWebView's (that are subviews of a UIScrollView) receive touch events?

My controllers and views are set up as follows:

```
HomeViewController.h /.m /.xib
HomeView.h /.m (is a UIScrollView)
DashboardViewController.h /.m /.xib (custom UIWebView's)
```

HomeViewController is loaded from a Nib file that contains a custom view: HomeView.
DashboardViewController is loaded from a Nib file. It contains a few labels, sliders, etc. (note that there is no custom view here - I am not subclassing UIView here).

HomeViewController dynamically loads several DashboardViewControllers and adds its view to the HomeView.

```
DashboardViewController *dashboardViewController = [[DashboardViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DashboardViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle];
[homeView addSubview:dashboardViewController.view];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The User Interaction is standard enabled.

Did you connect your views delegate to the File's Owner? 
And did you bind your View to the Controller? And make sure you connect the corresponding actions to the correct methods. (CTRL Click on the View and drag the plus sign onto the corresponding method in your Class.h file.

```
@interface MyScrollView : UIViewController {
    UIView *myFirstView;
    UIView *mySecondView;
    UIView *myThirdView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *myView;

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

@end
```

Comment: Yes, my views delegate is connected to the File's Owner. What do you mean bind my View to the Controller? Also, I've connected the UIScrollView subclass as the main view for the Controller. See my updated post; I've added some more information that might help. Thanks.

Comment: This solution doesn't work as the UIWebBrowserView (not the UIWebView) seems to pick up the touch events. This class however, cannot be subclassed to alter the functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for [`canCancelContentTouches`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/canCancelContentTouches).

```
scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set `userInteractionEnabled = YES` for all the subviews?

Comment: userInteractionEnabled is enabled by default.

Comment: Oops. Thought it was NO by default. contentSize on the scrollView maybe?

Answer (score 0):

UIViewController gets the touches* messages before the UIView. The UIViewController doesn't pass the message along to the UIView (by calling [super touchesBegan]) by default. So you need to move or forward the touches* functions if your UIView has a controller.

Personally I put the various touches* methods on the view subclass, not the view controller subclass.

Comment: The problem here is that I don't subclass UIView for the views that are subviews in the UIScrollView. I just use the view generated from the Nib. See my updated post; I've added some more information that might help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, when you get the touches methods being called for UIScrollView in turn you can call the same touches method in subview from scrollview.